# Тень по центру, css, полукруглая тень

Tags: css

Как сделать такую тень как на рисунке? т.е. чтобы тень как-бы расширялась к центру
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это скорей всего картинка. `box-shadow` так не сделаешь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если другого варианта не найдете: создаем под данным элементом овал с тенью и делаем его немного меньше по высоте, чем данный элемент. Если с размытием и растяжение поиграться, то можно сделать идентичную тень.

```css
.out {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 150px / 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 43px 7px -35px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}

.in {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 86px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="out"><div class="in"></div></div>
```